# Using Hengstler C56 USB Thermal Printer in Android

Tags: java, android, linux, printing, thermal-printer

I am trying to use a Hengstler X-56 USB Printer (http://www.extendo-printer.de/en/products/x-56-series/) in Android. I am using Android x86 right now and was planning on trying to use their linux drivers and possibly including the drivers in the init.rc startup. Does anyone have a good/possible solution to printing to a USB thermal printer either through a device node or via C/Java?

Comment: Their website has a linux driver, but it's binary-only. Since you are on x86 it may be possible to find a way to use the binaries, but I suggest asking the manufacturer for the source code.

Comment: I took a closer look at the driver. It seems the easiest solution would involve installing a full-blown Debian chroot on your device, which could run a cups daemon. You could then use the binary driver as-is to install the printer as a cups endpoint, and on the android side your java app could use some standard remote-printing library.

If you can't go with the chroot (e.g. don't have root access) you could use their "emulation" interface. This would involve writing some native code to access their API, statically linking it to pull in the libc dependencies, and calling it through JNI.

Comment: Thanks Adam. This is route I have been going. I've grabbed and included the library and api into a JNI build with Android and so far seems to be loading it...The only piece I'm hung up on is Exo_Api_PrinterOpen (PrinterPort); i.e. what would the address be here? I don't notice anything in /dev/ when i plug in, but dmesg and lsusb both recognize the device.

Comment: Also another note. I plugged it into Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked right out of the box...dmesg even shows "Hengstler" as the vendor and looks like it has drivers built in. I was able to echo "test" > /dev/usb/lp0 and print directly too it. I was hoping to get this in Android as well and utilize just printing directly...